# Templates / polymorphism

Tags: c++, class, templates, polymorphism

I'm trying to make use of polymorphism. Basically, there's a class-name missing in the middle of the code. As I'm not used to templates, could someone give me a clue? Thank you

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H``
#define TEMPLATE_H


using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Template
{
public:
      Template(int);
      virtual  ~Template();
      virtual  void push(T val);
      T pop;
      virtual  bool isFull();
      virtual  bool isEmpty();
      virtual  void  sizeOf(T val) ;
    protected:
    private:
    int top,size;
};

#endif // TEMPLATE_H

#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

/***LIFO***/

using namespace std;

template <class S>
class stack: public Template{ // HERE, it says it's missing an expected class 
-name before {
    public:
        stack();
        virtual ~stack();
    protected:
    private:

};

#endif // STACK_H
```

Comment: You can't inherit from `Template` because `Template` is not a class. You could inherit from `Template<int>`, `Template<std::string>`, `Template<S>` or so on.

Comment: Should be `template <class S> class stack: public Template<S> { // ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack` should inherit from `Template<S>`, not `Template`.

`Template` is not a class.  It is a class *template*.  `Template<int>` would be a class, or `Template<std::string>`.  You cannot inherit from a class template, only from a class (or struct).

Comment: How come it doesn't inherit from Template<T>  instead of Template<S> ?

Comment: It can inherit from `Template<Whatever>`.  I picked `S` because that's the existing (and unused) template parameter to `stack` in OP's example code.